# Host timeout during file upload/download over SFTP/SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, sftp

I've tried different clients because I thought it was client related. All of them eventually disconnect, or stop transferring files - followed by getting a timeout disconnect. After a reconnect it works again for a bit of time. It is really strange, I can not figure out the reason.

I'm on a Mac, and the server is a VPS running Debian. If you need further information, please ask!

I appreciate any tips, because I'm kinda stuck!

Comment: My guess is that somewhere along the way, there is a loss of connectivity for a while long enough for the SSH-connection to die off.  This sounds like a network issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try running tcpdump at both ends and analyze the results in Wireshark. You should see which packets get stopped and retransmitted: that will help you to debug it.

Answer (score 1):

Wireshark will give you a "bandwidth graph".  Here is an old example from Ethereal days:

[image]
<sub>(source: [wireshark.org](https://wiki.wireshark.org/RTP_statistics?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=RTP_graph_analysis2.gif))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

What is the network like between the mac and server?
Is it possible you are having an MTU (transmission unit problem), that is, you are sending a packet that is to big? This can happen with some DSL providers.

- Greg

Comment: I hear this "guess" all the time but have never seen anyone able to prove it in any way.

Comment: If you're on a connection with a reduced MTU (such as a DSL PPPoE link) and the other end blocks ICMP "destination unreachable / fragmentation needed" messages then you have a PMTU black hole. The situation is common enough that many vendors have added black hole detection to their IP stack: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc958871.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What does `ssh -vvv` produce when you try to connect to the remote server ?
And what are the results of `traceroute` and `ping` to your server ?

On the VPS server you could install something like [Smokeping](http://oss.oetiker.ch/smokeping/) to see whether the connection of the server to your IP experiences intermittent problems.